# on click clone the li and show in a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

on click of li, clone it and show in a div and if clicked on other li it should show newly clicked li.

Below is my code and codepen. if feel I am missing something.
https://codepen.io/AnthonyDavid/pen/xxqmqQY

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).each(function(i) {
    $("<div class='special'>")
      .append($(this).contents().clone())
      .appendTo('#container');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">First</a></li>
  <li><div>Second</div></li>
  <li><span>third</span></li>
  <li><h4>Fourth</h4></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It is working, right? Except the `<a href>` which would by default reload the page and if you need to avoid that, catch the click event and do event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the click handler for a tag, so the page won't redirect, instead will work with the functionality as expected.

Updated the snippet with only one item at a time.

```js
$('li').click(function(event) {
  $(this).each(function(i) {
    var data = $("<div class='special'>")
      .append($(this).contents().clone())
    $('#container').html(data);
  });
});

$('.list-wrapper a').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<ul class='list-wrapper'>
  <li><a href="">First</a></li>
  <li><div>Second</div></li>
  <li><span>third</span></li>
  <li><h4>Fourth</h4></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how to clear and append? show only on li at a time @Abin Thaha

Comment: Updated the snippet with clear and append.

Answer (score 1):

prevent any event on click `a`

```js
$('li a').click((e)=>{e.preventDefault();});
$('li').click(function() {
  $(this).each(function(i) {
    $("<div class='special'>")
      .append($(this).contents().clone())
      .appendTo('#container');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<ul>
  <li><a href="">First</a></li>
  <li><div>Second</div></li>
  <li><span>third</span></li>
  <li><h4>Fourth</h4></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: how to clear and append? show only on li at a time @לבני מלכה

Comment: when do you want to clean and when to append? (do you want something like toggle?)